# Habilitar href con e.preventDefault(); y sin que deje de funcionar el resto de código

Tags: href

Cuando pincho en a href no me lleva al sitio al tener e.preventDefault(); pero si que me realiza el efecto configurado. Cuando quito e.preventDefault(); me funciona los href pero no me funciona el efecto. Me gustaría que funcionaran las dos cosas al mismo tiempo.

```
    <div class="nav-lang">
        <div id="selector"></div>
        <a id="langEsp" href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?la=esp">ES</a>
        <a id="langCat" href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?la=cat">CA</a>
        <a id="langEng" href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?la=eng">EN</a>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#langEsp").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#selector").addClass("selector0");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector2");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector1");
    });

    $("#langCat").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#selector").addClass("selector1");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector0");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector2");

    });

    $("#langEng").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#selector").addClass("selector2");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector1");
        $("#selector").removeClass("selector0");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería mejor que desde el servidor aplicara el *efecto* al ingresar a cada enlace, de lo contrario sería forzoso introducir un retraso en cada event handler para hacer visible el *efecto* por un momento y luego causar una redirección, de lo contrario el cambio de clases no será visible salvo mientras se establece la conexión al sitio redireccionado. Si insistes en hacerlo así, sería, por ejemplo, para el selector `#langEsp`:

```js
$("#langEsp").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#selector").addClass("selector0");
    $("#selector").removeClass("selector2");
    $("#selector").removeClass("selector1");

    // en este contexto this es el elemento seleccionado por #langEsp
    var _this = this;

    // redireccionar en 1 segundo (1000 milisegundos)
    setTimeout(function () {
        // redireccionar al enlace indicado por el atributo href
        location.assign(_this.href);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias don_aman. La verdad es que soy bastante novato y no sé muy como hacerlo, pero llevas toda la razón, lo suyo seria hacerlo desde el servidor. A ver si soy capaz de hacer algo.